# How to get .ready to be called each time an element is loaded in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domready

I'd like to have an event that fires every time a Dom element is initialized, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="data">data!</div>
</div>

<div id="clickme">Click me!</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#container').html('<div id="data">data '+i+'</div>');
        i++;
    });

    // this event gets called only the first time #data element is ready
    // I want it to be called each time #data comes into being
    $('#data').ready(function() {
        alert('element data ready!');
    });
});
```

---

I've tried:

```
// doesn't work
$('#data').live('ready', function() {
    alert('element data ready (live)');
});
```

**Edit:** I am interested in doing that for elements that are inserted by ajax. For example:

```
$.post('/myaction/', {
     param: 'value'
  },
  function(data) {
      $('#someContainer').replaceWith(data);
  });

  // this function operates on elements returned by the ajax call, so they are not available at this point.
  myFunction();

  // so I'd better call myFunction() when the ajax data is inserted
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nf8CP/

Comment: Why would you need an event? Why not just invoke the code at the time when you create the element?

Comment: what do you mean by element is initialized?

Comment: I think "ready" is when window.onload initiates, and document.readyState is == "complete" .. and that happends only once!

Comment: @user1689607 I have an form that is loaded when you get the page the first time, and then after each ajax call. I think its more elegant put the javascript for the form in `.ready('#myForm')` than both at $(document).ready and in the ajax call.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I mean `element is initialized` when it is inserted in them dom.

Comment: @pinouchon: This is what functions are for. What is inelegant about invoking a function when you need the behavior? FYI, `$('#data').ready(function() {` ignores the `#data`  selector. It is invoked when the entire DOM is ready. Not just when that element is ready.

Comment: @pinouchon: RE your updated question, since you already have a function call, why wouldn't you just put it inside the `$.post` callback after the `.replaceWith()`?

Answer (score 2):

*For your updated question, just move your function to the callback, and you're done.*

```
$.post('/myaction/', {
     param: 'value'
  },
  function(data) {
      $('#someContainer').replaceWith(data);

      myFunction(); // Call it right here.
  });

 // myFunction();  // Not here!!!

});
```

---

There are DOM Mutation events, but I believe they're deprecated, and don't have full browser support.

There's also the `livequery` plugin, but it's really overkill.

The `.ready()` handler does not handle loading events for individual elements. Only for the DOM loaded events. These three examples all have the same behavior:

- `$(document).ready(...`
- `$('document').ready(...`
- `$("#data").ready(...`
- `$().ready(...`

There is no difference. The argument passed to `$` is ignored.

The proper solution is to invoke the code you want when you create the element.

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#container').html('<div id="data">data '+i+'</div>');
        dataReady();
        i++;
    });

    function dataReady() {
        alert('element data ready!');
    }
});
```

Also, given your example, a better and less destructive solution would be to simply modify the text in `#data` instead of destroying the element with `.html()`.

Comment: This example is to simulate a new element being loaded to trigger the .ready function. (I am interested in catching the event, not changing the element text).

Comment: @pinouchon: I understand that. My point is that if you're the one loading the elements, you should just run the code when you create them instead of hoping for an event system. *(Unless of course you don't control the code that makes the DOM modifications.)* There's no fully cross-browser event to handle that.

Comment: @pinouchon: Actually, I gave two solutions that are on topic. The DOM Mutation events and the `livequery` plugin. Neither are recommended. The `.ready()` method only does one thing. It invokes handlers when the DOM is ready. It doesn't target individual elements. You may think it does, because it works when you do `$("#data").ready(...`, but in reality, it ignores the `"#data"` part.

Answer (score 1):

`ready` (or more accurately [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded)) only fires once, when the page has been fully parsed. There is no clean way to do what you're wanting here, so you're going to need to go with manual installation of your event handlers. (There are the DOM mutation events, but those are so noisy, your page will eat itself trying to handle them, and it's generally a bad idea unless you really know what you're doing).

However, I suspect that what you really want here is event delegation. You need to install the event on `#container` rather than `#data`, because when your ready function is called, the existing `#data` node is removed from the DOM!

For example:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#data', function() {
  alert('#data element was clicked!');
});
```

What this does is install a handler on `#container` (which never changes), which listens for `click` events originating (or bubbling through) a child element with the selector `#data`. This means that even if you keep replacing the contents of `#container`, you never have to install new event handlers on its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DOMNodeInserted`:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    alert('element data ready (live)');
});
```

It will be fired whenever a node is added to the DOM.

You can also filter what nodes trigger this event like so:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '#data', function() {
    ...
}
```

Now it will only trigger when nodes with the ID of `data` are added.

Comment: -1 for not mentioning browser incompatibilities for this solution. And also for putting the handler on  `document` instead of on `"#container"`.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you put your .ready inside of your button click, so you can see if it is ready every time you click it:

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#container').html('<div id="data">data ' + i + '</div>');
        i++;
        $('#data').ready(function() {
            alert('element data ready!');
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Why would you use the `.ready()` system instead of just invoking the code directly? The `.ready()` adds nothing here.

Comment: it is what the asker wanted. Checking if the #data is ready.

Comment: But `.ready()` doesn't do that. The `.ready()` only checks if the DOM is ready. It ignores the selector. Anyway, there's no need for a "ready" check. The line of code to execute is *after* the `.html("...")` call, so obviously the element will be ready.